# how to build a orm query where says if the model doesnt exist (object) add , but if exist then change the modified fields?

Tags: python, django

I am new with django framework , and I would like to know how to build the following query where I can perform insert operation when the object doesn't exist, but update modified fields if there is an object with the following id

```
from demo.models import Person
update_values = {"name": "Alice", "age": 12, "is_manager":False}
new_values = {"name": "Bob", "age": 25, "is_manager":True}
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(identifier='id',
                                               defaults=update_values)
if created:
    print(f"created {obj}")
else:
    print(f"updated {obj}")
```

note:

I want to do it with a single method update_or_create than using two get_or_create + update_or_create

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. It seems like you're doing it correctly with the assumption that identifier="id" is what you're filtering on. What your code translates to is `obj = Person.objects.get(identifier="id"); [setattr(obj, k, v) for k,v in defaults.items()]; obj.save()` and then if its doesn't exist it inserts all those kwargs and defaults. In other words, I think your `identifier="id"` may be wrong. I think you meant `id=a primary key value` like 1,2,3,etc.

Detailed and really a better explanation from the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Just note that whatever you do requires two queries regardless.